# Drupal 9 view filter on a boolean type field

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

Drupal 9
Have content type Article.
Content type Article has a field, called "Need Further Review", of boolean type.
This field is not required, default value FALSE.
The articles has value TRUE, FALSE, NULL for this field.
TRUE: select true
FALSE: select false
NULL: the previous articles still have no value for this field.

Have a view to list articles.
A filter criteria is this field "Need Further Review", and is exposed.
It has options: Any, TRUE, FALSE.
When users select TRUE, it will list articles with TRUE value of this field.
When users select FALSE, it usually lists articles with FALSE value of this field.
Now want to list articles with FALSE and NULL value of this field.

Drupal 9 view query alter
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/9.0.x
Use hook_views_query_alter

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you create an Article, the field gets a value, either TRUE or FALSE (default). So your view only needs to have an exposed filter for these values.

It is only when you do a migration without setting the field, you will have no value. Or when you add this field later, when there are already Articles made.
Assuming this is the case, one solution is to set the field on those Articles to FALSE manually through the UI.

When there are too many Articles, and if you are able and willing to do some manual queries in the database, you may add the rows in the database for those Articles with a script, something like this (change to fit your situation, and, of course, make a backup first ;):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSW", "DATABASENAME");

if($link) {
      // get node id's
    $nids = array();
    $q_nids = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `nid`,`type` FROM `node` WHERE `type` = 'article' ORDER BY `nid`");
    $n_nids = mysqli_num_rows($q_nids);
    if($n_nids!=0) {
        while($l_nids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_nids)) {
            foreach($l_nids as $key => $value) {
                 // insert missing rows
                mysqli_query($link, "
                    INSERT INTO `TABLENAME`.`field_need_further_review`
                    (`bundle`,`deleted`,`entity_id`,`revision_id`,`langcode`,`delta`,`field_need_further_review_value`)
                    VALUES ('".$l_nids['type']."','0','".$l_nids['nid']."','0','nl','0','0');
                    ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or when you add this field later, when there are already Articles made. - This is the situation. When we created the field, there are already Articles made, and this field value is NULL for these Articles.
But we do not want to process the existing Articles, and just leave NULL value there. If users update the articles, the field will be set.
So for this field, there are TRUE, FALSE, NULL value for this field in the articles.
We have this field as exposed filter, and like to include NULL records when selecting FALSE option.
hook_views_query_alter looks solution.